# Multiprocessing Pipe send() blocks

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-3.6

According to Python documentation, only `recv()` blocks but not `send()`. I wrote the following code trying to make a GUI sudoku game. I made it in such a way that I can update the game board even if the `tkinter` is executing its `mainloop`. However, during a test run, I found that if I close the window while the game is updating, the `pipe.send()` starts to block (I found that out using CPython profiler.) Can anyone please tell me why and, if possible, how to fix this issue?

To produce the issue: close the poped up window while the script is updating. That is, close the window while some numbers are printed to console.

My system: macOS Sierra 10.12.5

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import random
import time
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # Python3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk  # Python2

class VisualizedBoard:
    def __init__(self,input_string,pipe):
        '''input_string: a string has a length of at least 81 that represent the board from top-left to bottom right.
        empty cell is 0'''

        self.update_scheduled=False
        self.pipe=pipe

        # create board
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=500, height=500)
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(50, 50, 500, 500, width=2)
        for i in range(1, 10):
            self.canvas.create_text(25 + 50 * i, 30, text=str(i))
            self.canvas.create_text(30, 25 + 50 * i, text=str(i))
            self.canvas.create_line(50 + 50 * i, 50, 50 + 50 * i, 500, width=2 if i % 3 == 0 else 1)
            self.canvas.create_line(50, 50 + 50 * i, 500, 50 + 50 * i, width=2 if i % 3 == 0 else 1)

        for i in range(81):
            if input_string[i] != '0':
                self.canvas.create_text(75 + 50 * (i // 9), 75 + 50 * (i % 9), tags=str((i//9+1,i%9+1)).replace(' ',''),text=input_string[i], fill='black')

        self.canvas.pack()
        self.root.attributes('-topmost', True)

        self.root.geometry('550x550+%d+%d' % ((self.root.winfo_screenwidth() - 550) // 2, (self.root.winfo_screenheight() - 550) // 2))
        self.root.wm_protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',lambda :(self.root.destroy()))
        threading.Thread(target=self.listen, args=()).start()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def update(self,coordinate,value,color='magenta'):
        """
                :parameter coordinate: a tuple (x,y)
                :parameter value: single digit
                :returns: None
        """
        try:
            assert isinstance(coordinate,tuple)
        except AssertionError:
            print('Update Failed. Coordinate should be a tuple (x,y)')

        coordinate_tag=str(coordinate).replace(' ','')
        self.canvas.delete(coordinate_tag)
        if value != 0 and value != '0':
            self.canvas.create_text(25+50*coordinate[0],25+50*coordinate[1],tags=coordinate_tag,text=str(value),fill=color)

        self.postponed_update()

        #self.canvas.update()

    def postponed_update(self):
        if not self.update_scheduled:
            self.canvas.after(50,self.scheduled_update)
            self.update_scheduled=True

    def scheduled_update(self):
        self.canvas.update()
        self.update_scheduled=False

    def new_board(self,input_string):
        self.root.destroy()
        return VisualizedBoard(input_string,self.pipe)

    def listen(self):
        try:
            while True:
                msg=self.pipe.recv()
                self.update(*msg)
        except EOFError:
            self.pipe.close()
            tk.Label(self.root,text='Connection to the main script has been closed.\nIt is safe to close this window now.').pack()
        except Exception as m:
            self.pipe.close()
            print('Error during listing:',m)



class BoardConnection:
    def __init__(self,input_string):
        ctx = mp.get_context('spawn')
        self.receive,self.pipe=ctx.Pipe(False)
        self.process=ctx.Process(target=VisualizedBoard,args=(input_string,self.receive))
        self.process.start()

    def update(self,coordinate,value,color='magenta'):
        """
        :parameter coordinate: a tuple (x,y)
        :parameter value: single digit
        :returns: None
        """
        self.pipe.send((coordinate,value,color))

    def close(self):
        self.pipe.close()
        self.process.terminate()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    b=BoardConnection('000000000302540000050301070000000004409006005023054790000000050700810000080060009')
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(5000): #test updating using random numbers
        b.update((random.randint(1, 9), random.randint(1, 9)), random.randrange(10))
        print(i)
    print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: what is the point of using multiprocessing? If you want to loop over a stream of random numbers, you don't need multiprocessing.

Comment: @BryanOakley the random numbers are for testing the GUI. In the real case, the program will attempt to solve the sudoku puzzle from user input and showing the process of search in the real time. I think it is not possible to conduct the search in the same process when tkinter's `mainloop` function is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python `Pipe` is an abstractions on top of OS nameless pipes.

An OS pipe is generally implemented as a memory buffer of a certain size within the kernel. By default, if the buffer fills up the next call to send/write will block.

If you want to be able to continue publishing data even if no consumer is consuming it, you should either use a `multiprocessing.Queue` or `asyncio` facilities.

The `multiprocessing.Queue` employs a "limitless" buffer and a thread to push the data into the OS pipe. If the pipe gets full the caller will continue running as the published data will be piled up in the `Queue` buffer.

IIRC, asyncio sets the pipe `O_NONBLOCK` flag and waits for the pipe to be consumed. Additional messages are stored within a "limitless" buffer as for the `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought that with some high level cross platform languages like python, OS doesn't matter anymore but...guess not

Comment: Unfortunately not. The `Pipe` in particular is pretty flawed. IMHO better to provide OS specific interfaces in cases like this rather than trying to abstract them as it's a very hard task.